# Jitsi Meet Installation on Windows

Tags: jitsi

I have been checking out Jitsi Meet platform. It seems promising to be used in my project. I am unable to install Jitsi Meet on Windows server. There is no proper documentation available for installation on Windows platform.

Please share the steps/video to install and host Jitsi Meet on windows server.

Answer (score 4):

I am late to answer, but I want to share some info with other people trying to run jitsi-meet on Windows. You can't use Prosody, so we will switch to Openfire.
You can than go the embarrassingly simple way (install Openfire Meetings plugin through Openfire administration and you have jitsi-meet running), or the adventurous and not-that-simple way (built from sources):

1. Install Openfire, most values stay default or are based on your configuration.
2. Enable http-bind.
3. Install Jitsi Focus Conference plugin (Jifoco)
4. To build the libs, you will need NodeJS and Python27 installed (I will assume you know how to use NodeJS). Clone the repository, install the dependencies and make some minor changes to webpack.config.js to actually build the sources on windows. I didn't manage to get them through PR, but I think I covered all of the changes in this Issue: https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/issues/1975
5. Change the config.js to point to your Openfire installation (I cheated here a bit and installed the OFMeet plugin to Openfire, opened the Jitsi-Meet window and copied config.js contents through Developer Tools - set up to connect to openfire)
6. Replace the virtual script includes to normal html includes and point them to your libs
7. You can use the libs to start jitsi-meet as you please. For example: I just created an empty Asp.Net MVC web application, changed the MVC router, added index.html and libs and it worked. (I remember having some problems, but they were tied more to MVC than to jitsi-meet)

I hope I didn't forget something. If you need anything specific, feel free to contact me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm one of the Jitsi developers and we have never tested this on Windows AFAICT, so I'm afraid you are on your own.

Some of the components of our projects require compiled libraries which we only provideo for Linux and macOS, so a nontrivial amount of work would be needed to address that.

Comment: is it possible to change the html/layout of jitsi-meet login and room ?

Comment: Sure thing. But please create new questions instead of hijacking others.

Comment: sorry and thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43347530/how-to-change-layout-of-jitsi-meet

Answer (score 0):

- I created a folder and download and extract the latest release in this folder, this is the link - https://github.com/jitsi/docker-jitsi-meet/releases/latest
- Create a .env file by copying and adjusting env.example that came together with the archive above.
  Set strong passwords in the security section options of .env file by running the following bash script below. To do that open PowerShell with Administrator and inside the folder that have you extracted, and execute the command:
  `./gen-passwords.sh`
- Create required CONFIG directories, copying and past the command in the PowerShell for Windows: `echo web/letsencrypt,transcripts,prosody/config,prosody/prosody-plugins-custom,jicofo,jvb,jigasi,jibri | % { mkdir "~/.jitsi-meet-cfg/$_" }`
- Run `docker-compose up -d`
- Wait a few minutes until Docker is up.
- Access the web UI at `https://localhost:8443` (or a different port, in case you edited the compose file), and you can use the self-hosting application with Jitsi Meeting.
- I'm considering that you already has Docker and Window 10 installed on your machine.
- Original link:
  https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/devops-guide/devops-guide-docker