# how to change layout of Jitsi Meet

Tags: jitsi

Maybe I'm wrong ... but as far as I know all Jitsi Meet element (home and room page) build using script that has been minified and also some of them connected to files inside jitsi server.
Is it possible to change the layout of Jitsi Meet html (home/room) base on my custom layout? how?

Comment: I flagged your question as better suited for ServerFault. The focus of StackOverflow is programming actually.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to build the sources with your changes. Please see: https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet#building-the-sources

Comment: I'm not sure what people expected from this answer. As one of the Jitsi developers, this is the only way to create a custom layout.

Comment: So I have no experience with React.  The stock answer is Please see: https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet#building-the-sources  - the instructions are:

`sudo apt-get install npm nodejs
cd jitsi-meet
npm install`

What am I supposed to have in jitsi-meet?  I've done a quick-install, and it's not created a jitsi-meet folder in my home directory.  Presumable that's where I'm supposed to be doing this?  Tried downloading one of the source files and extracting it here, npm install results in a bunch of errors.

There seems to be no clear guidance other than installation, which works great.

Comment: @saghul How about using lib-jitsi-meet for a custom UI?

Comment: @SMUsamaShah You can do that, yes. That's what Jitsi Meet is actually: a GUI for lib-jitsi-meet. It is, however, a complex one at that.

Answer (score 3):

When you install `jitsi-meet`, indeed the files are in `/usr/share/jitsi-meet`. But these aren't really the source files and those cannot be easily changed.
In order to change that page, you need to check out the project source code from https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet, make your change, run `npm install && make` as stated in the README and then make sure your web server uses your checkout folder instead of `/usr/share/jitsi-meet`.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use lib-jitsi-meet to create a custom layout as described in this dev community post. 
https://community.jitsi.org/t/jitsi-dev-jitsi-meet-video-conferences-with-a-custom-gui

Answer (score 0):

Jitsi uses React.js and Redux for the frontend and without modification of source code and rebuilding process, it is practically not possible to change the layout. for more detail, you can check [how to modify the Jitsi app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72433676/customizing-jitsi-meet/72931026#72931026) post

then you should change your build with the old one on the server at this location: /usr/share/jitsi-meet/libs (if you have not change the source location manually in Nginx config)