# Customizing jitsi meet

Tags: jitsi, nodejitsu, lib-jitsi-meet

I'm building a web application with video conference, I'm using jitsi opensource for video calling, I have searched several forums but not able to customize for my needs. How can we do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the react side of view & build the jitsi, unfortunately lots of people using it as is, they are only changing the logo & background :) and some of them putting an auth ( which can be bypassed easily ) in front of jitsi.
If you need modification & building custom solution & more control ( not just ui but both for the spec of meeting )
I suggest you to give a try https://github.com/edumeet/edumeet I like this project ;)

Comment: could you please confirm you are referring to this library: [ https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet ] ?

Answer (score 1):

You need node v16+ and any Linux OS

1. `git clone jitsi-meet`
2. `npm install`
3. Learn react because you need knowledge of it to change the functionality but you can start with simple things e.g changing the text so go to `jitsi-meet/lang/main.json` change some text that you want to change.
4. Type the `make` command in terminal
5. Then, change your whole source code with the original one on the server and you will see the result